# Nested Sets in mySQL with a left join

Tags: mysql, left-join, nested-sets

Could anyone please explain to me, why this mysql query throws an "Unknown column 'n.Id' in 'on clause'" error? It really doesn't make any sense to me.

```
SELECT n.Id,
       n.Name,
       COUNT(*)-1 AS level,
       seo.URLName
FROM NestedSetsTable AS n,
     NestedSetsTable AS p
LEFT JOIN SEO__Table AS seo
ON seo.ElementId = n.Id
AND seo.ElementCat = 1
WHERE n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND n.rgt
GROUP BY n.lft
ORDER BY n.lft
```

Basically, the NestedSetsTable has the columns Id, Name, lft, rgt and the seo table has an
ElementId (which contains the id of the Categorie), ElementCat (which contains a int, 1 in this case for categories, 2 would be products for example), URLName (which contains the name for a clean url. example.com/Categories/myCleanName for example )

Thank you

edit: I solved this problem, but the reason i'm asking anyway is because I want to figure out why n.Id is unknown in the ON clause because it really makes no sense to me.

Comment: I am not positive, but I would have to guess it was because you combined the ANSI join style with the theta style.  How did you fix it?

Comment: I fixed it by simply subselect the URLName like this:

SELECT n.Id, 
       n.Name, 
       COUNT(*)-1 AS level, 
       (SELECT seo.URLName FROM SEO__Table AS seo WHERE seo.ElementId = n.Id AND ElementCat = 1) AS URLName
FROM ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join syntax is incorrect. I'm not sure how you want to join your two references to NestedSetsTable, so for now I'm assuming it's an inner join on Id. Also, I don't remember off-hand how MySQL handles grouping but typically you'd need to group on all non-aggregate columns in your query, e.g. `n.Id, n.Name, seo.URLName`

```
SELECT n.Id,
       n.Name,
       COUNT(*)-1 AS level,
       seo.URLName
FROM NestedSetsTable AS n
CROSS JOIN NestedSetsTable AS p
LEFT JOIN SEO__Table AS seo
ON seo.ElementId = n.Id
AND seo.ElementCat = 1
WHERE n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND n.rgt
GROUP BY n.lft
ORDER BY n.lft
```

Comment: I'm afraid, I think the join syntax should be okay, especially because if you switch n.Id against p.Id there is a correct output of all Categories and levels, just the URLName is the one of the top-parent of each categorie.

I got the basic query from this tutorial of nested sets (http://www.klempert.de/nested_sets/#kap3 (it's in german))

In your example, the level is always zero, because of the inner join.

Comment: @Fitzi The join in the example you've referenced is a cross join on n and p, so I can update my example based on that.

Comment: Yeah, a cross join works on this one, but the level is incorrect again (just count's up each row).

And I already solved the problem by putting a subselect in the select, I'd just realy like to know, why n.Id is unknown in the example above.

Comment: Because in the example above you're left-joining p to seo, not n to seo.

Comment: Okay, I didn't knew that the order of the tables in den FROM clause matters, i just tried FROM NesteSets AS p, NestedSets AS n LEFT JOIN... and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Now this seems more logic to me.

Answer (score -1):

Move the criteria `AND seo.ElementCat = 1` to the `WHERE` clause:
....

```
LEFT JOIN SEO__Table AS seo ON seo.ElementId = n.Id WHERE n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND n.rgt AND seo.ElementCat = 1
```

...

Comment: That won't affect the "unknown column" n.Id in the on clause

Comment: Some SQL environments will throw misleading error messages when the syntax states to do a join, however the join can't be parsed because you haven't defined both columns on which to do a join.  "= 1" is not a defined column.  But thanks for the down-vote buddy! lol

Comment: I'm sorry, but the syntax is right.
Brian Driscoll just explained why my problem hasn't worked. (look in the comments of his answer)